# date conversion in oracle for Fri Nov 23 2018 format

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert "Fri Nov 23 2018" into a mm/dd/yyyy format in Oracle 12c, I tried but didn'tfind a proper solution, kindly help me on this

Comment: Are you starting with a string value, or is that actually a date (coming from a DATE column) and that's just how your client/IDE is displaying it? It might be helpful to edit your question to explain where that value is from (or at least what data type it is), what you have tried, and what errors you got.

Comment: Please, show your code and table structure with datatypes. Date storage and date display are different tasks

Answer (score 3):

Convert your string to a `DATE` data type *(note, a `DATE` is a binary data-type and has no defined format so it is just being used as an intermediate step)* and then back to a string in the desired format:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           'Fri Nov 23 2018',
           'Dy Mon DD YYYY',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
         ),
         'mm/dd/yyyy'
       ) AS formatted_date_string
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | FORMATTED_DATE_STRING |
> | --- |
> | 11/23/2018 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e0031885d1404c8e6e08f8d7c7bce9c)*